# How to set a callback function to be the first callback in EventEmitter?

Tags: node.js, callback, eventemitter

I have a shared event emitter say myEmitter.

```
myEmitter.on('fire', callback1); 
myEmitter.on('fire', callback2); 
... 
myEmitter.on('fire', callbackN);
```

Now the problem is: I want `myEmitter.on('fire', myTopCallBack);` and I want myTopCallBack to be the first callback function to be called when 'fire' event happens.

Is it possible to subscribe a callback as the first callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`emitter.prependListener()`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_prependlistener_eventname_listener):

```
myEmitter.on('fire', callback1); 
myEmitter.on('fire', callback2); 
... 
myEmitter.on('fire', callbackN);

myEmitter.prependListener('fire', myTopCallBack);
```

Comment: That's what I want. Thanks mate.